# Java Support on Win RT

Tags: java, javafx, windows-8, tablet, windows-rt

I have an application written in Java FX. Will this run on Win8RT or Windows on tablet. If not, Is there any mechanism via which I can port to code to run on WIN 8 RT platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaFX application will run on a Windows tablet (e.g. Windows 8 tablet like a Surface Pro); it will not run on Windows RT.  [Supported JavaFX 2.x platforms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) are listed on Oracle's support site.

There are ongoing community efforts to port [JavaFX to run on Android](https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/how_to_build_open_javafx) and [iOS](https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/ipack_the_ios_application_packager) (based on [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net), [OpenJFX](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/) and [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.org) or [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)), but no current efforts to port JavaFX to run on Windows RT.